# Use wordpress in the background for a static Website

Tags: wordpress, web, static

How can  use a static html website on wordpress in the "background" so to speak, i wont need to edit or change the site in any way, i just need the website to be in wordpress.

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what you mean, this question is a little confusing. Are you asking can Wordpress generate a static site? If so, no, that's not what Wordpress does. If this is what you need look at static site generators such as Gatsby, Jekyll etc.

Comment: You might also want to check out https://www.getshifter.io/

Comment: Basically im using my former websites uploading them on httrack, i just need to upload them with wordpress to use a specific plugin, the plugin isnt wordpress specific so it would work on all sites i just dont know how to modify it, so i want to use the static websites under wordpress just to use the plugin, i dont really care about functionality

Answer (score 0):

technically yes, you can just create a custom theme and convert your "static website pages" into page templates in your theme. then create pages on the CMS side then assign the page templates respectively.

Comment: i see, is there a way to do that very quickly or automatically ?

Comment: not automatically or programmatically, but its fairly easy to do it. if you want i can give you the steps if you think you are going this path.